# Javascript small calculator app giving nan result

Tags: javascript

Help with this code :) i try to calculate price and i all time get nan result  tnx in advance.

Basicly i try to insert this code in view of codeigniter page

But i dont know how to get rid of Nan result

```js
<div class="calculator"> <!--calculator test-->
<div id =a><?php echo $Data->var_price1; ?></div>
<div id =c><?php echo $Data->var_price2; ?></div>
 <input id="odrasli" type="number">
 <input id="deca" type="number">
 <input type="button" value="Get Price" onClick="mycalculator()">
<script>
function mycalculator() {
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var x = document.getElementById("odrasli");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var y = document.getElementById("deca");
var aa = a * x;
var cc = c * y;
var p = aa + cc;
var d = p * 0.2;
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = p;
document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>
</p> Grand total </br><p id="price"> </br>
 Deposite<p id="depozit"></p> </br>

 </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns the whole html element, not a number. For the `div` ones, you need to do something with it, e.g. `Number(a.innerHTML)`. For the `input` ones, you need to do e.g. `Number(x.value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet and remember casting to Integers or Floats with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

```js
function mycalculator() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").innerHTML);
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("odrasli").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").innerHTML);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("deca").value);
  var aa = a * x;
  var cc = c * y;
  var p = aa + cc;
  var d = p * 0.2;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = p;
  document.getElementById("depozit").innerHTML = d;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div id="a">2</div>
  <div id="c">3</div>

  <input id="odrasli" type="number">
  <input id="deca" type="numbear">
  <input type="button" value="Get Price" onClick="mycalculator()">
  <div id="price"></div>
  <div id="depozit"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns an html element. To get the numeric value of these elements try

```
var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").innerHTML);
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("odrasli").value);
var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").innerHTML);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("deca").value);
```

Comment: `parseInt` will truncate e.g. `123.45` and I have a sneaking suspicion OP isn't going to like that.

Comment: nice !! The same!! XDD :) curious!!

Comment: @Crayon Violent  good point, switched it to parse float so it will keep decimal values